# es6 equivalent for module.exports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export, require, es6-module-loader

What's the ES6 equivalent for module.exports

I want to get the value of foo from an import statement

```
module.exports = {
    foo: function (a) {
    }
}
```

Tried:

```
export default {
    foo: function (a) {
    }
}
```

The way first one is imported is using:

```
var file;
var filename = root + "/" + fileStats.name;
file = require(path.resolve(filename));
```

I want to use ES6 import statement. I read somewhere that this isn't supported however would like to still know if there's a work around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do because in the code you supplied you did not consume the actual foo method from the object you imported.

But if I understand correctly, you could achieve this in one of 2 ways:

```
export default function foo(a) { };
```

and consume the module with:

```
import foo from './<filename>.js';
```

Or alternatively, don't use the default export:

```
export function foo(a) {};
```

and consume with:

```
import { foo } from './<filename>.js';
```